# Rotating toroid with external magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it possible to make toroidal coil spin with external magnetic field that is circular symmetric?
I thought that toroidal coil is similar to set of circular rings. And every single circular current has a magnetic dipole moment. If these dipoles receive magnetic force that is perpendicular to the radial direction, then toroid will receive torque from external magnetic field. Is it possible?